# Preventing an infinite loop on a setter in JS/TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, infinite-loop, setter

With TypeScript, I've been trying to set up what I call a "trigger" : an object that contains a **checker** function (returns a Boolean) and a **behavior** function, which can do basically anything.
What I want to do is every time a certain variable's value is changed, the **checker** function of the trigger is executed, and if it returns true, the **behavior** function is ran too.

Naturally, I put the trigger's **checker** function call in a setter :

```
set health(value: number) {
    this._health = value;
    runTriggers();
}
```

The goal of a trigger's **behavior** function is to do anything, but mainly **change values from variables**.
And that is where the problem is : if a trigger is called in the *health* setter like above, and the behavior function of the trigger also changes the *health* variable (thus calling the setter again), it will end up in an infinite recursive call.

How could I prevent this infinite call from happening, while still allowing my trigger's behavior function to freely change variables?

Comment: I suspect the real answer here will be to fundamentally redesign how you're doing this, which would be well beyond the scope of an SO question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is likely to be **very** dependent on your overall design choices. Fundamentally, you have to have a way to say "don't do an infinite loop," which means that somewhere, sometime, something is going to have to be able to set `health` *without* running triggers.

A simple flag would let you avoid even one recursive trigger call:

```
set health(value: number) {
    this._health = value;
    if (!this._healthTriggerActive) {
        this._healthTriggerActive = true;
        try {
            runTriggers();
        } finally {
            this._healthTriggerActive = false;
        }
    }
}
```

...but that of course means that setting `health` in a trigger callback won't run triggers (since that's the basic problem).

You could also limit depth with a counter, allowing a certain amount of recursion but not too much; but that's probably just hiding the problem.